# How to elegantly read string with delimiters?

Tags: c++

Firstly consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char delim = '\n';
    char inp;
    int cnt = 0;
    multiset<char> m1;
    while (cin.get(inp) && cnt != 2)
        if (inp == delim)
            cnt++;
        else
            m1.insert(inp);
    multiset<char> m2;
    while (cin.get(inp).peek() != '\n')
        m2.insert(inp);

    ...
}
```

I wanted to read input like this:

```
SANTACLAUS
DEDMOROZ //read characters of first 2 strings in m1
SANTAMOROZDEDCLAUS //read characters of this string in m2
```

Code look messy. And quite hard to debug. But still I need to read somehow character by character. Of course I can do reading through strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    multiset<char> m1;
    string inp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> inp;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < inp.size(); j++)
        {
            m1.insert(inp[j]);
        }
    }
    cin >> inp;
    multiset<char> m2;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < inp.size(); j++)
    {
        m2.insert(inp[j]);
    }
    ...
}
```

But still I feel somewhat bad for using extra memory. Can I achieve the elegant solution for this problem without using extra memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## refactor to avoid duplication

Your instincts are good:  **Don't Repeat Yourself**.
You have identical blocks of code with only one variable changed.  You should break this out into a function, making the changeable part a parameter to that function.

```
    multiset<char> m1;
    string inp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cin >> inp;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < inp.size(); j++)
        {
            m1.insert(inp[j]);
        }
    }
```

In this case, you abstract out `m1` as the return value, and `i` as the parameter.  Just doing this you get:

```
auto scan_n_lines (size_t lines)
{
    multiset<char> m;
    for (size_t i = 0; lines < 2; lines++)
    {
        string inp;
        cin >> inp;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < inp.size(); j++)
            m.insert(inp[j]);
    }
    return m;
}
```

Now you can *use* this twice in your original code, rather than typing it twice.

```
    multiset<char> m1 = scan_n_lines (2);
    multiset<char> m2 = scan_n_lines (1);
    ...
```

## meanwhile

[Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

Prefer using prefix `++`.

---

Process each character in the string using a ranged `for` loop, not a C style counting loop.  There is no `j` and no need to subscript the string.

```
for (auto ch : inp)
    m.insert(ch);
```

But look at the class:  `insert` can do an entire range at once.  You don't even need the loop!

```
m.insert (inp.begin(), inp.end());
```

So, review [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert) for the library components you use.  You know that a set (or multiset) has `insert` as an essential operation, but do you know it has 8 different forms?  Memorize the essentials of what the class does, but rely on the docs for details as you use it.

---

Finally, the outer loop is just to repeat `n` times.  In C++20, you can use `std::ranges::iota`.  If it's not available as part of the compiler's library, use a different library or [your own simple version](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1245139/DIY-range).

````
auto scan_n_lines (size_t lines)
{
    multiset<char> m;
    for (auto i : std::ranges::iota(0,lines))
    {
        string inp;
        cin >> inp;
        m.insert (inp.begin(), inp.end());
    }
    return m;
}

```
````